# Best way to send message to IBM Websphere MQ from C# .net CF 3.5 running WiN CE 6 devices

Tags: c#, windows-ce, ibm-mq, .net-cf-3.5

I am new to IBM websphere MQ and am looking for best way to send message from win CE 6 device using c# .net CF 3.5 app to MQ.
I have searched and found that WebSphere MQ Telemetry and a MQTT client can do this. 
Is there any other way? Can i do it with plain IBM websphere MQ 6 or 7.5 ?
If WebSphere MQ Telemetry and a MQTT client is the only way.... can someone please explain the architecture for this. How to setup MQ and how to start writing a client?

Thanks for reading and apologies if i didn't make my query clear.
Regards,
Zia

Answer (score 0):

MQ .NET client is available for a full fledged .NET Framework, not available for Compact .NET Framework. So you will need to use a MQTT .NET client and connect to MQ. There are number of MQTT .NET clients available. You can use any of them to develop your application.

Here is some information on setting up MQTT channel in MQ: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.adm.doc/q021270_.htm

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the MQTT client for Windows CE and .Net Compact Framework 3.5, there is the M2Mqtt library as part of the Eclipse Paho project :

https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.m2mqtt

Paolo.

Answer (score 0):

facing the same concerns to connect to AWS.IoT from cfnet 3.5 + wince 6...

the big issue with working in cfnet 3.5 is that there is no support for System.Net.Security and System.Security.Authentication (afaik); so you can't use SSL.

If SSL is needed, you'll need to use native libraries such as paho.mqtt.c + openssl.